# Should we `enable` the Systemd User service `pulseaudio.service`?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, systemd, services

Checking my pulseaudio config, I just realized there is a `/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service` provided by the `pulseaudio` package.

It is disabled, but `pulseaudio` works completely fine without. Have been using it for a year. Don't need to do anything after boot to start the actual executable. (It's an Ubuntu shipped-in package after all.)

Why is it so ? Should I enable the service ? If so, why doesn't Ubuntu do this by default ? Also, what will change from current operation ?

Thanks in advance

PS: The Ubuntu wiki page doesn't give any information.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt why did you flag this and not close as a duplicate?